# fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/

Tags: gitlab, release, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-runner

I came across this authentication error while trying to do a release.

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/[project_name]/[repo_name].git/'
/builds/[project_name]/[repo_name]/deploy/change-log.js:30
        throw error;
        ^
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a lead on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's an `Access denied` error, and because the code contains an `ACCESS_TOKEN` env var, that token might have been revoked together with their account.

Creating a new [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#create-a-project-access-token) and [injecting it as a custom variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#custom-cicd-variables) should help solve *that* problem at least.

Comment: I changed the group variable and it worked. Thank you :)